# Refresh page after form submit

Tags: php, forms, web-applications, web

My site allows users to edit it in real time. I'm having problems on some areas where when you submit the form it doesn't change until I re-launch the page

so it only displays the icons that have text in the DB and when I add a new link in and submit it changes the value in the backend and should change on the front as I relaunch the page with header("Location: admin.php"); (see below)
http://snag.gy/lmR8s.jpg

If I press refresh it tries to send the data again. What I have to do is click the url and enter to re-launch the page and the change it made
http://snag.gy/vDI90.jpg

```
$submitSocial  = $_POST['submitSocial'];
if(empty($submitSocial)){
    include("includes/social.php");
} else{
    $submitFB = $_POST['fb'];
    $submitTW = $_POST['tw'];
    $submitYT = $_POST['yt'];
    $submitLI = $_POST['li'];
    $submitTL= $_POST['tl'];
    $submitFL= $_POST['fl'];
    $changeSocial = $change->changeSocial($userID, $siteID, $submitFB, $submitTW, $submitYT, $submitLI, $submitTL, $submitFL );
    if($changeSocial){
        include("includes/social.php");
        header("Location: admin.php");
    } else{
        header("Location:  N/A.php");
    }
}
```

Is there anyway round this as I need it to reload with the things changed first time?

Comment: write the change before you read the values!

Comment: Mr. Alien, that's for test purposes, it's only me using it right now.

Comment: If i am getting your problem correctly ...you should use AJAX for this.

Comment: x4rf41, what do you mean? It needs to read the values to put in the change.

Comment: @web2students.com What's wrong in including file even if he is redirecting? what if that file holds some variables/code which should be executed before redirection?

Comment: web2students, because when I didn't put in the include("includes/social.php"); that section went blank like so: http://snag.gy/5Okk6.jpg

Comment: If you don't re-direct to other page, then it will show update value?is that you want?

Comment: yes, I want it to show http://snag.gy/vDI90.jpg without refreshing the page again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your code that populates the fields initially? Just call this after you save the changes

Comment: Surprisingly that worked. I'd have thought when the page refreshed it called that function again. It's like this now. http://pastebin.com/P0sLgRBe

A little messy, but it worked. Thanks